# How can I equip a psion shaper without being reduced to clothless poverty?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, psionics

Here's the story:

All I wanted to do was make an honest-to-god no cheese robot-building psion. But to make a very mediocre creature that deals a whooping 1d6 + 9 damage with an attack at level 9 I would have to spend more time than most encounters lasted.

I eventually gave up and made a telekinetic thrust combo build (where you shoot 8 objects, each dealing +2d6 damage due to psionic shot).

I wanted to buy items to make my life easier, but magic items are overwhelmingly expensive. A rod of quickened power 3x per day costs a whooping 170k gold.

Here is the build:

[Sheet](http://www.myth-weavers.com/sheet.html#id=26024)

Male True Neutral Gray-Elf lvl 6 Shaper Psion / lvl 3 Constructor, **Level** 9, **Init** +0, **HP** 35, **Speed** 30 ft. / 6 sq.

**AC** 11, **Touch** 10, **Flat-footed** 11, **Fort** 7, **Ref** 3, **Will** 11, **Base Attack Bonus** +4, **Power Points** 78

**??? Elven longsword**   (1d8, x2)

**Headband of Intellect +2**, **Bracers of Armor +1** (+1 Armor)

**Abilities** Str 5, Dex 11, Con 12, Int 22, Wis 16, Cha 16

**Powers**

Level 1:

> Astral Construct
>
> Bolt
>
> Inertial Armor
>
> Vigor
>
> Ecto protection

Level 2:

> Identify, psionic
>
> Control sound
>
> Levitate
>
> Share pain

Level 3:

> Concealling Amorph, Greater
>
> Time hop
>
> Telekinnetic thrust
>
> Telekinnetic force

Level 4:

> Fabricate, Psionic
>
> Divination, Psionic
>
> Intellect Fortress
>
> Dimension Door, Psionic

**Feats**

> 1- Boost Construct
>
> 3- Psionic Shot
>
> 6- Permanent Focus(psionic shot)
>
> 9- Knowledge Devotion
>
> Bonus 1- Psicrystal Affinity (Artiste)
>
> Bonus 5- Narrow Minded
>
> Bonus flaw 1- Improved Psicrystal (Observant)
>
> Bonus flaw 2- Point Blank Shot

**Flaws**

> Noncombatant (-2 melee)
>
> Elven Pride of Arms (Can only use elvish arms)

**Remaining gold**

> 20k

What items can I buy to either make my astral construct not such a disappointing power or make my telekinetic thrust combo not miss 70% of the arrows I fire?

Comment: You need to specify a system. Is this D&D3.5? In addition, you may want to actually ask a question. This is just a rant. Do you need help with anything?

Comment: Yeah, the system you are using is really important to be able to answer this

Comment: Rants aren't acceptable here, including those that are thinly veiled as questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a rant in disguise. There is no question here, and [ranting is explicitly off topic](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: There's a fair question buried in this frustration: *How can a level `X` psion with `Y` feats and `Z` gp in a campaign using sources `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. spend his money so that he can create awesome astral constructs?* But considering this question's already poisoned, best to delete this question and ask anew.

Comment: @HeyICanChan adding a bit to the end of that question: _"(...) so that he can create awesome astral constructs without reducing himself to clothesless poverty?"_

Comment: I thought people would get the question from the title. Apparently at 5AM I don't think right.

Comment: What I want to know is basically "where the mage 99 cent store at?". I actually changed it because apparently people don't like answering "why do rolexes cost 100k dollars?" questions.

Comment: Your question remains adversarial and too broad. You've provided a class; now provide a character level and feats. Then narrow the available textual resources. Consider explaining the campaign's premise and providing some details of your adventuring companions. The more information you provide, the better answers will be. If all you want is cheap, good magic items, that's a question for a forum; if you want laser-like focus on what to buy for *your* character, here's the place.

Comment: What I wanted was actually cheap good generic magic items. I'll change the question for that specific character then.

Comment: What book is Permanent Focus from?  I can't find it in the XPH or the CP.  Also, what flaws did you take?

Comment: Hyperconscious book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Items aren't going to make a huge difference in your offensive capabilities.**

Boosting Astral Constructs through items isn't very easy. There is the [Amulet of Advanced Construction](https://web.archive.org/web/20190913143851/http://archive.wizards.com:80/default.asp?x=dnd/pse/20020727c), which can grant additional options to your Constructs, but it overlaps somewhat with the Constructor abilities.

Aside from that, the best I can think of is a Torc of Power Preservation (Magic Item Compendium p. 143) for 4k to make the Constructs cost fewer PP, which allows you to make bigger and more impressive Constructs slightly sooner. This is a good item for all Psions, regardless.

Using items to boost your attack rolls with Telekinetic Thrust is also rather difficult. You could buy magic arrows, but that gets expensive fast. You technically could afford to buy a better Headband of Intelligence, which would help. Probably a tiny bit soon, though.

**Items *can* make a difference in your ability to survive.**

There are quite a few bases you haven't covered with your powers yet in the defense department. I have compiled [the most relevant item categories here](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?187851-3-5-Lists-of-Necessary-Magic-Items).

I will assume that Psionic Levitate and Psionic Dim Door will be covering your flight and teleportation needs for now, but there are still things that immediately spring to mind (within your character's budget):

- A Third Eye Clarity (Magic Item Compendium 141). Helps with stunning and dazing. Those pop up all the time. 3000gp.
- A Scout's Headband (Magic Item Compendium 132). For those times that an invisible attacker makes everything un-fun. 8000gp.
- Talisman of Undying Fortitude (Magic Item Compendium 188). Grants short-duration plethora of bad things that can quickly become relevant in an encounter, from ability damage to paralysis. 3400gp.

Assuming you also go with the Torc of Power preservation, this leaves you with a comfortable 1600 gp out of your stated budget.

All of these are cheap items that you may want to replace once you hit higher levels.

**You still have problems on the offense?**

As I said, item choices aren't really what's going to help you make the character more powerful. A Psion's *offensive* capabilities are primarily defined by their power and feat selection. Sorry!

In your particular case, buff *spells* from allies could also make a huge difference. If you have a Cleric on the team, try getting them to cast party-friendly buffs like Recitation and Righteous Wrath of the Faithful (both are in the Spell Compendium).

But overall, I think you may be underestimating your Constructs just as they are. There's more potential there than "1d6+9 damage" already.

Comment: Isn't the torc 36k? It says so in expanded psionics(172)

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho The updated version in the Magic Item Compendium costs only 4k, but comes with a uses/day limitation.

Comment: I found out I had illegal feats in my build so my DM allowed me to reboot (YAY!). I picked up quicken power, metapower(quicken power), and 3x infused construction. That way, I can make constructs as a swift action for free. Also got myself ectoskeleton so I can pilot them like gundams. Turns out I didn't need items after all! (Except for the torc). With the leftover money I got a nice pair of gloves of ecto manipulation to give me better menu options.